# Rendering cursor image

Tags: geotools, rendering

How do I get the CURSOR_IMAGE

(/org/geotools/swing/icons/mActionZoomIn.png)
to be rendered as nice as the ICON_IMAGE
(/org/geotools/swing/icons/mActionZoomIn.png) in GeoTools map example application?

```
 /** Cursor */
public static final String CURSOR_IMAGE = "/org/geotools/swing/icons/mActionZoomIn.png";

/** Icon for the control */
public static final String ICON_IMAGE = "/org/geotools/swing/icons/mActionZoomIn.png";
```

I had to take a photo of the screen to get the cursor, can't do it with print screen or capture.
This is the cut out of that image, where the PNG is put into a button:
[image: This is the cut out of that image, where the PNG is put into a button:]
This is the cut out from the same photo image of the cursor (same PNG as in the button).
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and some code to clarify your question?

Comment: Added images to my question.